# Restore deleted AWS Cloudformation stack

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Does anyone know if there is a way to restore deleted stack on AWS Cloudformation? I can see the deleted stacks in the Filter but there is no option to restore them.
If restore is not possible can i recreate the same stack?

To give little background, my application is running on elasticbeanstalk and i did not realize it creates cloudformation stack for Autoscaling. I deleted it and then realized all my deployments fail. So wondering if i can restore it.

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: I just deleted my website by mistake! Exactly like you, I deployed it with Elastic Beanstalk and when I checked into CloudFormation half a year later while following some tutorials, I noticed there were a lot of stacks, so I deleted them, bc I thought they were from my previous tutorials... AWS should flag the resources and make clear where they came from. I was able to restore it with Beanstalk but still...

Comment: @G-Unit what abput the rds service? how did youu restore that?

Comment: That's too long ago, don't remember, sorry!

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way: go to your Elastic Beanstalk environment and choose "Rebuild environment". AWS will recreate everything from scratch, including CloudFormation stack.

Comment: what you should do to restore the rds afterwards?